# Setting margin on an ImageView

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm trying to set the imageview's layout_marginTop to one value for different density/screen sizes.  In my values-mdpi folder I have the following line in dimensions.xml

```
<dimen name="marginTop">10dp</dimen>
```

In the MainActivity

```
ImageView image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.s_image);
```

But there is no setmargin method for imageview.  Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need to do that in code, you can do it in your XML file where the image view is defined.  See [this page](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/more-resources.html) for more details.

```
<TextView
    android:layout_height="@dimen/textview_height"
    android:layout_width="@dimen/textview_width"
    android:textSize="@dimen/font_size"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

You're on the right track. It's probably easiest to refer to your dimension value within the xml (rather than set this up in java code).

```
<ImageView
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/yourMarginTopValue" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Try try to put `android:adjustViewBounds="true"` to

Answer (score 0):

It's probably better to do it in XML since you seem to already have the `ImageView` defined in XML.

However, the `layout_*` XML attributes refer to the `LayoutParams` of the parent layout, not the view itself. To change them in code, access them with `getLayoutParams()`, do your modifications and call `requestLayout()` to schedule a re-layout pass. For example:

```
ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams lp = (ViewGroup.MarginLayoutParams)imageView.getLayoutParams();
lp.topMargin = 123;
imageView.requestLayout();
```